# Exchange 2013 - 0kb EDB File after ISCSI Drop

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, database, exchange-2013, edb

I am unsure if anyone will be able to help me out.

I have a 0kb EDB file after an ISCSI failure.

I cannot run "eseutil" on the file as I get the error:
        Extensible Storage Engine Utilities for Microsoft(R) Exchange Server
        Version 15.00
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

```
    Error: Access to source database 'Z:\ExchangeDB\Mailbox Database 1440466717.edb' failed with Jet error -1206.

    Operation terminated with error -1206 (JET_errDatabaseCorrupted, Non database file or corrupted db) after 0.16 seconds.
```

Comment: If the file is 0KB then I don't see how eseutil would run against it. What type of backups of the mailbox database do you have?

Comment: Are you certain that any hardware failures are resolved?
You might have a better chance from locating backups, and bring it back to date with transaction logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the database file is 0KB in size, then there's just nothing there. No amount of `eseutil` can recover anything from an empty file.

You should fix the (probably serious) underlying storage problems, and then hope the database comes back unscathed. Otherwise... let's just hope you have good backups.

Comment: Underlying problem fixed!

Comment: The EDB was living on an ISCSI LUN separate to the rest of the network...

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the database using following steps:

**First Method**

1. If cache is enabled via OST files, You can export the entire contents to PST
2. Log-in to Exchange Server& Stop Exchange Server Information Store
3. Now Go to your log directory, Select the files that you wish to delete and press “Del.” Make sure not to delete recently created log files. Exit the directory.
4. Restart the Exchange Server Information Store. This will resolve your issue!

****Second Method****

1. Rename the folder where the 0kb EDB is located, create a new folder with the original name. Same for log file path associated with the 0kb EDB.
2. Now mount that database and it will show that EDB files are missing. If you are able to create new one then a new EDB file will be created. After that All the mailboxes associated with EDB file will be working. This will resolve your issue!

You can also check this blog on error: [Operation terminated with error -1206 (JET_errDatabaseCorrupted, Non database file or corrupted db)](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/resolving-exchange-database-consistency-check-failed/)